# Lógica SELECT CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, lógica

gostaria de ajuda na construção da seguinte lógica:

Tenho minha tabela principal e outras duas tabelas A e B, que possuem chave estrangeira da principal.

Quando uma coluna X estiver preenchida na tabela A preciso classificar minha informação como sendo do "tipo 1"
Quando existir qualquer campo na tabela B sendo que B.id_estrangeiro = P.id_principal. Preciso classificar minha informação como sendo do "Tipo 2"

Mas, no campo X da tabela A há alguns preenchidos somente com virgula ','
nestes casos, mesmo quando tiver preenchido com virgula e não existir nada na tabela B então minha informação ainda é "tipo 1"

E se estiver preenchido somente com virgula ',' e existir registro na tabela B então ela sera somente do "tipo 2"

E por último quando a coluna X da tabela A estiver preenchido e existir registro na tabela B então é uma informação do "tipo 1 e tipo 2"

tabela principal:
[image: Tabela principal:]

tabela A
[image: tabela A]

tabela B
[image: Tabela B]

Como podem ver neste exemplo os ID's 1 e 3 da tabela principal deveriam ser classificados como tipo 1

o ID 6 deveria ser somente do tipo 2

e os demais id sendo como tipo 1 e dois

Com a seguinte query

```
select

(
CASE WHEN (A.de_inf is not null or A.de_inf != '') and A.de_inf != ','
        AND EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf IS NOT NULL OR tit_inf != '') 
            THEN 'Tipo 1 e Tipo 2' 

ELSE

    CASE WHEN A.de_inf = ',' or (A.de_inf is not null or A.de_inf != '')
                AND NOT EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf IS NOT NULL OR tit_inf != ''
            )  
                THEN 'Tipo 1'

ELSE

    CASE WHEN  A.de_inf = ',' 
        AND EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf IS NOT NULL OR tit_inf != '') 
        THEN 'Tipo 2'

                end 
                end
                end


) as tipo



from
principal as p

left join A on p.id_inf = A.id_inf
```

obtive este resultado

[image: exemplo]

ou também desta forma:

```
SELECT
p.id_inf,
 (
CASE WHEN A.de_inf != ',' THEN
CASE WHEN A.de_inf is not null or A.de_inf != '' THEN 
CASE WHEN  EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf IS NOT NULL OR tit_inf != '')  
THEN 'Tipo 1 e 2' ELSE 'Tipo 1'
END
end

else
'Tipo 2'
END
) AS tipo
from
principal as p

left join A on p.id_inf = A.id_inf
```

[image: exemplo2]

Comment: Se id=6 não existe na tabela B por quê seria Tipo 2? Ou sua descrição está errada?

Comment: O id=6 existe na tabela B, e na tabela A ele é preenchido somente com ',' então deveria ser do tipo 2

Comment: Não percebi, com as consultas que construiu já não tem a sua resposta? Se não, pode colocar uma imagem ou descrição de qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Se id=6 existe na tabela B então a tabela listada está errada ou incompleta.

Comment: A tabela está correta, porém não está ordenada no campo id_inf, o 6 está antes do 5. Que não vejo problema nisso, deve ter sido falta de atenção da galera.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é oque exatamente você quer mas a query abaixo chega ao resultado esperado por você:

```
SELECT (

CASE WHEN (A.de_inf is not null or A.de_inf != '') 

AND A.de_inf != ','

AND EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf IS NOT NULL OR tit_inf != '') 

THEN 'Tipo 1 e Tipo 2' 
ELSE
   CASE WHEN A.de_inf = ',' AND (A.de_inf is not null or A.de_inf != '')
            AND NOT EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where  B.ID_inf = A.ID_INF
        )  
            THEN 'Tipo 1'
ELSE

CASE WHEN  A.de_inf = ',' 
    AND EXISTS (select tit_inf from B where tit_inf != '') 
    THEN 'Tipo 2'

            end 
            end
            end

) as tipo,A.ID_INF

from
principal as p

left join A on p.id_inf = A.id_inf
```